# web.config redirect all requests to https://www

Tags: iis, web-config

We want to redirect all incoming requests to https://www.domain.com

- http://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
- http://www.domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
- https://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
- https://www.domain.com -> https://www.domain.com

We have tried dozens of code snippes from the web but none covered all the examples from above.

Can anyone help with an appropriate web.config file for IIS?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem. This rule works for me.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect non-www OR non-https to https://www">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to this is via your DNS records + some IIS configuration.

- Add a CName that redirects domain.com to www.domain.com
- In IIS, create a "fake" website and edit its binding to handle http://www.domain.com
- Configure an HTTP redirection in the web.config of this "fake" website (or through the UI) to redirect requests coming from the host name www.domain.com to https://www.domain.com$S$Q ($S and $Q allows you to keep the parameters after the redirect, see [this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/41c238b2-1188-488f-bf2d-464383b1bb08.mspx?mfr=true) link for more info)
- Finally, remove the HTTP binding your website (only use https binding on this one).

Comment: And this will also redirect https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com? We were able to redirect all requests to https://www.domain.com except this one: https://domain.com Any idea why that wasn't possible with the web.config file?

Comment: The CName will redirect this for you. It is not possible with the web.config file because this is DNS Record stuff, not application related (therefore, not the web.config's job).

The two things to remember :
1. DNS Records manage the "www" added
2. Web.config and IIS manages the forced HTTPS

Comment: Ok, do not hesitate to ask if you need more information. This is the settings I use for some of my production websites and it works fine.

If you do not want to use a fake site only to redirect to HTTPS, you can also use the global.asax file and force a redirection to HTTPS in the BeginRequest event (if you have many websites on the same server, it can get messy to have many redirects).